# Como enviar email para várias pessoas com o PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Gostaria de saber como faço para que o "para:" no email seja correspondente ao campo na tabela, ou seja, que por exemplo eu tenha dois emails, um email é `exemplo@exemplo.com` e o outro email do banco é `exemplo2@exemplo2.com`, eu gostaria de saber como faco para enviar o email para os respectivos, pois não consigo, somente consigo enviar para um só, eu gostaria que fosse assim a minha mensagem `para:exemplo@exemplo.com` só isso e sem mostrar os dois emails que foram enviados como fazer isso?

```
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM newsletter");
    while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ 

    $e = $aux['mail'];
    $mail->ClearAddresses($e);
    $mail->AddAddress($e);

    var_dump($e);
    }    
                        //se enviou com sucesso salvo este envio
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
```

Esse é o trecho de código que eu fiz, mas não deu certo, ele envia somente para 1.

OBS: No `var_dump($e)` ele me traz certinho todos os resultados do banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `ClearAddresses` limpa todos endereços, então acredito que no caso você estava tentando usar ele pra limpar endereços repetidos, mas conforme a documentação ele não tem parâmetro:

- https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_clearAllRecipients

Veja:

```
public function clearAddresses()
{
    foreach ($this->to as $to) {
        unset($this->all_recipients[strtolower($to[0])]);
    }
    $this->to = array();
}
```

Portanto a cada loop ele esta apagando todos endereços, ou seja apenas o ultimo ficará na lista de endereços, pra resolver o problema use um `array`, pra evitar as duplicidades deve ficar semelhante a isto (parece o seu objetivo):

- Com `array_unique`

  ```
  $todosEnderecos = array();

  $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM newsletter");
  while ($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
      $todosEnderecos[] = trim($aux['mail']);
  }

  $todosEnderecos = array_unique($todosEnderecos);

  foreach($todosEnderecos as $value) {
      $mail->AddAddress($value);//Adiciona os endereços
  }

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
      $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
      return false;
  } else {
      $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
      return true;
  }
  ```
- Com `in_array`:

  ```
  $todosEnderecos = array();

  $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM newsletter");
  while ($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
      if (in_array($aux['mail'], $todosEnderecos) === false) { //Verifica se o endereço já existe
          $todosEnderecos[] = $aux['mail'];
          $mail->AddAddress($aux['mail']);//Adiciona os endereços
      }
  }

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
      $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
      return false;
  } else {
      $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
      return true;
  }
  ```

> Note que o `trim` é necessário pois para o `in_array` ou `array_unique` os espaços no começo e no fim tornam strings diferentes, por exemplo:

```
joao@hotmail.com
```

é diferente de (tem um espaço no começo):

```
 joao@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque dentro de um laço de repetição, onde o cláusula de controle ( condição para terminar) seria a quantidade de registros no banco, ou seja, a quantidade de email's cadastrados no banco.

Ou então pode verificar se o requerimento da classe phpmailer está acontecendo apenas uma vez, do contrário, irá dá erro e só enviará a um email:

```
require("../class.phpmailer.php");
```

Comment: mas ja estou fazedno issso no meu while ele esta fazedno enquanto existir email que seria o  `$e = $aux['mail']`

Comment: Certo, eu fiz a mesma coisa uma vez e o problema estava no require("../class.phpmailer.php"), verifique isso.